# Missing id JSON - GET

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-java

I've made couple of registries in my database (mongodb), when i try to get @localhost:8080/ {for example company} info about collection I can't see ID of documents, which I clearly entered.

Any ideas how can i fix it and show id ?

```
{
    "name" : "google",
    "person" : null,
    "_links" : {
    "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/company/2"
}
```

Comment: All documents in MongoDB have an _id field which is unique and immutable. If you don't specify one, MongoDB will generate an ObjectId for you. So this document doesn't come from MongoDB or has been altered.

Comment: This JSON-Snippet looks broken. What is it for?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in MONGODB i can see id of object but this is the output of request-get @localhost:8080/company